# SQL Server order by with max rows in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

The following query works with PostgreSQL and I'd like to know why it doesn't work with SQL Server 2016.

```
select * from (values (1),(2)) as a(a)
UNION
(
  select * from (values (1),(2)) as a(a)
  order by 1 desc
  offset 0 rows fetch first 1 rows only
)
order by 1 desc offset 0 rows fetch first 1 rows only
```

Can anyone explain to me why order by would not be supported here?

Funny that the following, which is another way to express this, works like a charm

```
select * from (values (1),(2)) as a(a)
where a.a in(
  select * from (values (1),(2)) as a(a)
  order by 1 desc
    offset 0 rows fetch first 1 rows only
)
order by 1 desc offset 0 rows fetch first 1 rows only
```

Is this a bug?

Comment: Ordering by ordinal position is a bad habit anyway. Right along with select *. When ordering you should use the column name instead of the ordinal position. What happens when you change the table? Suddenly your query doesn't work anymore.

Comment: This is just a minimal example to show the problem for demonstration purposes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query after the union needs to be presented as a select, like so:

```
select * from (values (1),(2)) as a(a)
UNION
select * from
(
select * from (values (1),(2)) as a(a)
order by 1 desc
offset 0 rows fetch first 1 rows only
) b
order by 1 desc offset 0 rows fetch first 1 rows only
```

Comment: Is that just a workaround that you found out about or is that the syntax how it is supposed to be used?

Comment: Well, sql server interprets the first version as 
        select * from (values (1),(2)) as a(a)
        UNION
       select * from (values (1),(2)) as a(a)
       order by 1 desc offset 0 rows fetch first 1 rows only
       order by 1 desc offset 0 rows fetch first 1 rows only

which isn't valid syntax. the extra select * makes it a proper subquery that sql server can parse.